# Array issue - Why array is filled by next rows?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a method that clear some arrays and then fill them.
I don't understand why the array dayTask is filled by the next rows of the console.log ?

```
showEventsList(day) {
    console.log('dayTasks A', this.dayTasks);
    console.log('dayEvents A', this.dayEvents);
    this.dayEvents = [];
    this.dayTasks = [];
    this.dayEvents.length = 0;
    this.dayTasks.length = 0;
    console.log('dayTasks B', this.dayTasks);
    console.log('dayEvents B', this.dayEvents);

    this.shareList.forEach((shareUser) => {
      if (this.currentUser.username === shareUser.username) {
        this.userEvents.forEach(e => {
          if (new Date(e.startTime).toString().substring(4, 15) === new Date(day).toString().substring(4, 15)) {
            this.dayEvents.push(e);
          }
        });
        this.userTasks.forEach(e => {
          if (new Date(e.startTime).toString().substring(4, 15) === new Date(day).toString().substring(4, 15)) {
            this.dayTasks.push(e);
          }
        });
      } else {
        if (this.shareUserEvents !== undefined) {
          this.shareUserEvents.forEach(e => {
            if (new Date(e.startTime).toString().substring(4, 15) === new Date(day).toString().substring(4, 15)) {
              this.dayEvents.push(e);
            }
          });
        }
        if (this.shareUserTasks !== undefined) {
          this.shareUserTasks.forEach(e => {
            if (new Date(e.startTime).toString().substring(4, 15) === new Date(day).toString().substring(4, 15)) {
              this.dayTasks.push(e);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Console:
[image]

if i comment the array filling part, dayTasks B is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console.log is async and therefore not evaluated immediatly. Which means you may see it evaluated after the array filling part. try getting a clone to be logged `console.log([...this.dayTasks]);`, your problem should disapear